# finding file in google drive based on id/interoperating previous developers code

Tags: google-apps-script

So I hope the question makes sense. I am relatively new to GoogleAppScripts. I have a client that has some Scripts that I am trying to interoperate and modify. In order to do so I need to find each document that is associated by 'id'. But when I search for the id in the search bar of drive,I just get the script file that I am working on because the id number is in the text. I need to find the particular sheets doc that is associated with a particular ID, plain n simple. There has to be an easy way to do this aside from writing a function and outputting the result...

Comment: How about `DriveApp.getFileById('fileid')`.  Learn more [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search bar in Drive doesn't do search by ID, however if you know the ID you can hand-craft the file URL & access it that way — if you have permission to access the file in question.  e.g. you could open a Drive file with a URL like `https://docs.google.com/{file-type}/d/{file-ID}`, where *{file-type}* is `document`, `spreadsheet`, etc, & *{file-ID}* is the ID you have in the code.

An alternative is to get the names of the files for which you have IDs, write the results to the log (i.e. `Logger.log(DriveApp.getFileById("your_file_id").getName());`) & then search for them by name in the Drive UI.

Comment: Yeah that’s pretty much what I’m doing I just figured there might be a simpler way, oh well